# bash: variables and quotes in quotes

Tags: bash, variables, escaping, quotes

I would like to set a variable in bash called test_var
Basically, I want echo test_var to output:

```
%let output="file_20120601.csv";
```

where 20120601 is a variable. I am trying to do this by using:

```
test_var='%let output="file_$1.csv";'
echo test_var
```

this doesn't work because $1 is not interpreted as variable, but interpreted as literally $1

Does anybody know how I can modify this to get it to do what I want it to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because of single quotes. They make everything literal.

```
$ var='123'
$ foo="\"%hi there file_$var\""

$ echo $foo
"%hi there file_123"
```

Answer (score 0):

this works too

```
test_var='%let output="file_'"$1"'.csv";'
```

because variables are not expanded between single quotes.
and we can concatenate strings between single quotes and double quotes just writing strings beside.